# Simple ContainerView causes "Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported."

Tags: ember.js

With latest Ember, the following simple ContainerView causes the error:

> DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA

I guess this is somehow related to the way I append the view into the controller,

Please note that if template in the sub views are compiled inline the error doesn't happen, it only happens when providing external template to the 'template' property of the view.

http://jsbin.com/uqawux/2/edit

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That deprecation message reference this [gist](http://git.io/EKPpnA), if you look the **migration paths: (WIP)** section, it have the following text:

> if you are creating views outside the context of a parentView (this
>   may not be recommended, but it is happening) you will want to make
>   sure to instantiate your view via the container itself.

```
this.container.lookup('view:apple')
// will provide a instance of apple view.
```

So you need to update your code to use the container instead of `App.FooView.create()`.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  show: function() {    
    var v = this.container.lookup('view:foo');    
    v.appendTo(App.rootElement);
  }
});
```

Depending of your version, you will receive a new warning message:

> DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on controllers are
>   deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object (show on
>   )

In that case put your action in a `actions` object:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    show: function() {    
      var v = this.container.lookup('view:foo');    
      v.appendTo(App.rootElement);
    }
  }  
});
```

This is a updated jsbin using the lastest ember version without warnings http://jsbin.com/uqawux/4/edit