# Ember rendering jquery plugin content based on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ has following usage:

```
$('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
  content: $('<span><img src="my-image.png" /> <strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')
});
```

In Ember I tried to do:

```
App.MapItem = Ember.View.extend
  didInsertElement: ->
      @$().tooltipster
        content: $(App.MapTooltip.create(item: @get('item')).renderToBuffer().buffer)
```

This works, but returns DEPRECATION message:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA
```

How could this be fixed or what other approach I could take to fill tooltipster content using Ember.View?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945369/simple-containerview-causes-using-the-defaultcontainer-is-no-longer-supported

Comment: the `container.lookup` i think is for internal use (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085749/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ember-container), so i would suggest to use a container view to dynamically add a child view http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/