# ember - adding dynamic views confusion

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm hoping someone can clear up confusion for me around adding views to ember.  My end goal is to be able to add a view programmatically.

My first attempt was to use what was outlined in the [ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/):

My code:

```
App.MediaPreviewContainer = Ember.ContainerView.create();
App.MediaPreviewContainer.append();
var mediaPreview = App.MediaPreviewView.create();
App.MediaPreviewContainer.pushObject(mediaPreview);
```

Seems pretty close to the initial example from the guide.  When I run this, however, I get a deprecation notice:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported [defaultContainer#lookup]
```

**First Question**: is the ember guide not up-to-date, or am I doing something wrong?

The deprecation notice had [this link](http://git.io/EKPpnA) attached to it, and I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19360337/763027) that suggested the following change to instantiate a view:

```
// executed within another view, so 'this' is an instance of that view
var mediaPreview = this.container.lookup('view:mediaPreview');
```

This worked like a charm, however, I couldn't find documentation about that property, or even acknowledgement that the property exists within the [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html).

**Second question**: does the only way to add a view programmatically involve using an undocumented property?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.  I'm beginning to question my decision to use ember.

I've found several answers on SO about how to get around the deprecation warning, but haven't found the reason why, or if I'm doing something wrong.